# SSRS Report subscription date parameters

Tags: reporting-services

The thing that I want to do is as follows
I have a SQL reporting services report that takes date parameter (I have two parameters as **Run_Report_From_Date_PARM** and **Run_Report_To_Date_PARM**. These dates are picked from the Datepicker). I want to create a subscription to the report that will run on 1st of every month and show the data for the prior month.

While making subscription if i choose 2016-08-01 for **Run_Report_From_Date_PARM** and 2016-09-01 for **Run_Report_To_Date_PARM** then the report is generating always with that date range only. But i need the date ranges modify automatically after every month(like for the next month From date should be 2016-09-01 and to date should be 2016-10-01 ).

Comment: You can base your parameter value on the queries, or you can move this function into the report's dataset queries.

Comment: Agree with @ajeh. Though, I'd go more towards a dataset or an expression in the default values of the parameters.

Comment: @ajeh & @ Kevin- I am new to SSRS so could you guys please elaborate your answer and make it understandable to me.

Answer (score 1):

What is simplest is to just use expressions to set the default values for these parameters.

For a start date of the first of last month:

```
=DateAdd("m", -1, DateAdd("d", 1 + -1 * DatePart("d", Today()), Today()))
```

For an end date of the last of last month:

```
=DateAdd("d", -1 * DatePart("d", Today()), Today())
```

However, if you don't want these to be the default values when executing the report, you can set up a hidden boolean parameter that you only set to true in the subscription settings.  That can be useful if you need to include formatting or default value tweaks in the subscription version of a report.

Comment: One or more report parameters have an invalid parameter value. 
 
am getting this error.

Comment: Does that error occur when you run the report, or just during the subscription?  If the latter, I would delete and recreate the subscription, making sure that it is set to use the default values.

Comment: getting that error during the subscription. could you please help me out?

Comment: I just deleted the existing subscription and tried creating new subscription but still getting the same error : ' 
One or more report parameters have an invalid parameter value.'

Comment: But the report executes properly in the preview?  Could you post a screen shot of your subscription's parameter settings?

Comment: Yes..the report executes properly in the preview. May i know in which date format above query executes e.g. 21/09/2016 or 2016/09/21 etc.

Comment: FYI..My date parameter is data type of DateTime.

Comment: You misunderstand; the Today and DatePart functions both return date values, not strings that are parsed into dates.  So the system's date format should be moot.  One of the reasons I asked about a screenshot of the parameter settings is that you should check any other parameters.  Particularly multivalue parameters or those that set their available or default values from a dataset.  At the very least, change subscription's parameter settings by typing explicit values for these dates and re-run it to see if you still encounter an error.

Comment: The date parameters are working fine when i specified the queries(that you have wrote over there) in Expression value. Data is being pulled correctly and sent via email to the user. But my concern is data should be sent as an email attachment(pdf,excel etc.) should not displayed in the email body.